# View thumbnails of all pictures in a Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I'm a runner, and after a race, people often [post with 278+ photos](https://www.facebook.com/c.aramboy/posts/25274111592202973) that I want to quickly search through.

Note this is not an album per-se. An example of an album that easily shows as thumbnails is [here](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.25301403352807130&type=3).

How can I show all photos of a post on one page, as thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at an update post generated when the user added the photos to their album.

If you look at the post carefully you will note the actual [link to the album](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?vanity=c.aramboy&set=a.25274051692208963) within that update:

[image: post with link to album]

Once you click the link you are  then viewing the user's Photo albums and have the typical thumbnails as you expect.

[image: Facebook user photo albumn]

Comment: How does this work for a post like [this one](https://www.facebook.com/supian.jalong/posts/7345768098837879)?

Comment: In that case use your approach to replace  the word `photo` with `media/set`. FB is optimized for mobile and for those users they are scrolling through the photos quickly unlike on desktop. I upvoted your approach. 

Comment: I will look into any other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Open a photo in the set and get its URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=25274086728872126&set=pcb.25274111592202973
```

Change it to be in this format:

```
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.25274111592202973
```

IOW, the important part from the original photo URL is (in this example) `pcb.25274111592202973`.